# Implications of an expected value on almost sure convergence

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, almost-everywhere

The question I'm trying to solve is shown below - from a practice qualifying exam in probability which has no posted solution (self study).  I really don't know where to start (even for part (a)) and am looking for some major help.

[image]

Am I supposed to apply one of Kolmogorov's two/three series theorem? Thanks for any ideas you have!

Comment: I believe (a) holds more generally for identically distributed $\{Z_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$, regardless of independence. I would use the fact that $E[\log^+(Z)]<\infty$ implies, for all $r>0$, that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}P[\log(Z)>rj]<\infty$.  More generally I am just using the fact that if $X$ is a random variable such that $E[|X|]<\infty$ then for any $r>0$ we have  $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[|X|>ri] < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have (a).  This means that $P(Z_n > e^{rn} \text{ i.o.}) = 0$ for each fixed $r > 0$ by the first Borel Cantelli lemma.  Choosing $r = -\log(\phi)/2 > 0$, then on the complement of the i.o. set, we have that there exists an $N$ s.t. for each $n \ge N$, $Z_n \leq e^{rn} = \phi ^{-n/2}$, so then $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty Z_n \phi^n \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty (\sqrt{\phi})^n < \infty$$ and then as the remaining sum is finite we have convergence a.s.

Comment: I'm still uncertain about (b), but I think this is also true - we can say by definition of convergence the series $P(Z_n > \frac{\epsilon}{\phi^n} \text{ i.o}) = 0$, and this is where we need the independence assumption because we want to use the 2nd Borel Cantelli lemma to say that $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty P \left(Z_n > \frac{\epsilon}{\phi^n} \right) < \infty$$ and this will imply the required result?  I haven't properly rearranged but this makes sense

Comment: Yes independence seems needed for (b). I believe the fact about $X$ holds more generally: $E[|X|]<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[|X|>ri]<\infty$ for all $r>0$, which may be useful for (b). I'm not sure what "ergodic" or "strictly stationary"  are intended to mean in (c). It is not clear if we have $\{Z_t\}_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}$ or $\{Z_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$.

Comment: I'm not sure about (c) either so I'm planning on just leaving it.  Regarding (b), I can't prove that it's true for $\phi \in (0, 1/e)$.  If $\phi \ge 1/e$, we have $1/\phi^n \leq e^n$ and then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\log^+(Z) > n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Z > \frac{1}{\phi^n}) < \infty$$ as the sum on the right dominates the one on the left term by term.  In the case of $\phi \in (0, 1/e)$, I can't find a choice of $\epsilon$ that works sufficiently.  Do you know how to reconcile this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) is answered in the comments

b) For $\phi \in (0, 1/e)$ you can modify @Michael's hint and note that if

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\log^+(Z) > rn) < \infty $$ for any $r > 0$, then $\mathbb{E}[\log^+(Z)] < \infty$, which means you can just modify your calculation in the comment for $\phi \in (0, 1/e)$ by

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\log^+(Z) > rn) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Z > e^{rn} )$$ and now pick $r$ s.t. $e^r = 1/\phi$.

c) Provided the indexing on $Z_t$s is from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, yes, this sequence is strictly stationary. To see that, note that shifting the indices of $Z_i$s does not change anything about the joint distribution of finitely many $X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, ..., X_{t_n}$ and the joint distribution does not depend on the absolute values of $t_1, t_2, ..., t_n$, but only their differences.

I think$^*$ sequence, since $\phi$ is a random variable, is not ergodic. To see that, formally, we have

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{t=-n}^{n} X_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{t=-n}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \phi^j Z_{t-j} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{j= \max(|k| - n, 0) }^{|k| + n} \phi^j Z_k \rightarrow \frac{1}{1 - \phi} \mathbb{E} Z $$

where we can swap sums because everything is non-negative. Since this limit is not trivial provided $\phi$ is not, by the ergodic theorem, this sequence is not ergodic.

$*$: I am not fully sure; in particular, I am very unsure about the limit. I am quite sure it isn't ergodic though, since the limit of this running average is going to depend on the value of $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it was very helpful!